# Check if CString is all lowercase

Tags: visual-c++

```
bool CSubliminalDlg::CheckIfWordIsUppercase(CString w)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < w.GetLength(); i++)
    {
        if(islower(w.GetAt(i)))
           return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above function keeps triggering a breakpoint. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Where is the 'breakpoint' triggered, and what does it say/what information is it giving you?

Comment: Expression: (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256

Comment: i have a feeling it has something to do with char checking...

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is the `CString` being wide-character, because you have Unicode defined as the default character set: all `TCHAR`s will be `wchar_t`, a wide type that in Visual Studio is 2-bytes.

Conversely, `islower` is a function that works on `char`, a 1-byte quantity. The breakpoint you hit is `islower` verifying that the input is actually within the range of a character (or `EOF`).

You should use `tchar.h` methods for working with `CString`, in this case `_istlower` which is the `TCHAR` variant of `islower`, `iswlower` or `_ismbclower`. Which one it is depends on the chosen character set, but the important thing is that is always uses the same set as `CString`.

To elaborate on this a bit: `tchar.h` defines aliases for (most) string functions in the standard library, automatically choosing the correct variant depending on the character set. So, whenever you find yourself using a method that works on C-strings, and you want to use it with `CString`, or `TCHAR` arrays, `LPTCHAR`, etc., you'll want to find the corresponding `tchar.h` alias for it and use that.